# Python SSH tunnel into EC2 and connect to DocumentDB

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, pymongo

I have been attempting to SSH tunnel into an EC2 instance and connect to DocumentDB that is located in the same VPC.  I've tried all of the solutions I could dig up online with no luck.  I am using the ssh_pymongo module, which wraps SSHTunnelForwarder.  I am able to SSH directly into the EC2 instance and connect to the DocumentDB cluster.  I'm trying to achieve this same thing via python.

Example code:

```
from ssh_pymongo import MongoSession

session = MongoSession(
    host='ec2-x-x-x-x.region.compute.amazonaws.com',
    port=22,
    user='ec2-user', # The user ec2-user is specific to EC2 instance OS Amazon Linux 2
    key='key.pem',
    uri='mongodb://<username>:<password>@xxxxx-docdb-cluster.cluster-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017'
)

# Note for the above function call: I've also tried various combinations of the to_host and to_port params without success.

db = session.connection['db-name']

print(db.collection_names())
```

Error:

```
Could not establish connection from local ('127.0.0.1', 36267) to remote ('xxxxx-docdb-cluster.cluster-xxxxxxxxxxxx.region.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017) side of the tunnel: open new channel ssh error: Timeout opening channel.
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin Ah my apologies, let me add that info to the original question.

Comment: Timeout often means problem with security groups. Can you double check them or show them?

Comment: @Marcin Security groups aren't the issue, as SSH is open to all, additionally I'm able to SSH manually from the same system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also tried the ssh_pymongo module but was unsuccessful.
However I tried directly with the sshtunnel module and I was able to query my database.

Here is my code

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from pymongo import MongoClient

# VM IP/DNS - Will depend on your VM
EC2_URL = '''*.*.compute.amazonaws.com'''

# Mongo URI Will depende on your DocDB instances
DB_URI = '''dbname.*.*.docdb.amazonaws.com'''

# DB user and password
DB_USER = 'dbuser'
DB_PASS = 'dbpassword'

# Create the tunnel
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (EC2_URL, 22),
    ssh_username='ubuntu',                # I used an Ubuntu VM, it will be ec2-user for you
    ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/keypair.pem',   # I had to give the full path of the keyfile here
    remote_bind_address=(DB_URI, 27017),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
)
# Start the tunnel
server.start()

# Connect to Database
client = MongoClient(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    port=27017,
    username='DB_USER',
    password='DB_PASS'
)


# Close the tunnel once you are done
server.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

kept getting this error

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: document_db_server:27017: 
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer,SSL handshake failed: document_db_server:27017: 
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer, Timeout: 2.0s, Topology Description: 
<TopologyDescription id: 63121b21cc3688a700cc86f9, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
servers: [<ServerDescription ('document_db_server', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>, 
<ServerDescription ('document_db_server', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: document_db_server:27017: 
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer')>, <ServerDescription ('document_db_server', 27017) 
server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: document_db_server:27017: 
[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer')>]>
```

the solution was to add `directConnection=True` to `MongoClient`

```
port = 27017
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (ec2_ip, 22),
            ssh_username=ec2_user,
            ssh_pkey=ec2_pem_key,
            remote_bind_address=(document_db_server, port),
            local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', port)

        )
server.skip_tunnel_checkup = False
server.start()
server.check_tunnels()
print(f"Tunnel is Up {server.tunnel_is_up}")
print(f"Local is up {server.local_is_up(('0.0.0.0', port))}")
print('---------------TUNNEL IS ESTABLISHED----------------')

"""DOCUMENT DB CONNECTION"""
client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        host="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?",
        tls=True,
        username=documentdb_user,
        password=documentdb_password,
        authMechanism="SCRAM-SHA-1",
        tlsCAFile=document_db_ca_pem_file,
        tlsAllowInvalidHostnames=True,
        timeoutMS=10000,
        directConnection=True
      )
```